# Why does my URL shortener sometimes redirect to the correct link but sometimes redirects to "URL not found"?

Tags: python, flask, url

I'm working on a simple URL shortener project using Python and Flask and deploying it to Heroku. Locally, it always works, however on my heroku site (here is the link: https://youareell-shortener-85ba6977de93.herokuapp.com/) I'll give it a long URL, then when it gives me a short one i'll click on it and it will redirect me to the correct site, I'll close the tab and click on the same short link again and it will say "URL not found".

```
import random
import string
import json
import os

from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request



app = Flask(__name__)
shortened_urls = {}

def generate_short_url(length=6):

    chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
    short_url = "".join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(length))
    return short_url



@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])

def index():
    if request.method == "POST":
        long_url = request.form['long_url']
        short_url = generate_short_url()
        while short_url in shortened_urls:
            short_url = generate_short_url()

        shortened_urls[short_url]=long_url
        # with open("urls.json","w") as f:
        #     print("TEST")
        #     json.dump(shortened_urls,f)
        #return f"Your shortened URL is: {request.url_root}{short_url}" #root url and the /something
        full_short_url = request.url_root + short_url
        return render_template("index.html", short_url=full_short_url)

    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/<short_url>")
def redirect_url(short_url):
    long_url = shortened_urls.get(short_url)
    if long_url:
        return redirect(long_url)

    else:
        return "URL not found", 404



if __name__ == "__main__":
    if os.path.exists("urls.json"):
        with open("urls.json", "r") as f:
            shortened_urls = json.load(f)
    else:
        shortened_urls = {}

    #app.run(debug=True)
```

This is my main.py.

I think it could be the fact I'm using a dictionary and not some sort of database? I was having an issue earlier where it was always returning URL not found and it was because my root URL was my server instead of my heroku domain. Adding that the issue could also be when I was installing the Heroku CLI I had to install Homebrew in which it gave me a warning that it could work incorrectly, not sure if this is it. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: did you write `shortened_urls` in file ? maybe it loads code again and it read old file without your `shortened_urls`

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: Depending on how your application is deployed it may run as multiple processes. Each of them will have its own version of `shortened_urls`.

Comment: @KlausD. How do I know if this is the issue? I'm not sure why it works fine every time locally but not once deployed

Comment: The local development server runs single processed. Production deployment usually run multi processed. To see check the logs on startup or print the PID by using the [`os`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getpid) module.

Comment: @KlausD. I'm noticing a new pattern where Image addresses or image links do not work without trying a few times, but website links always do. Also, I have to make sure the website has fully finished loading before copying the long url to paste, if i copy before it fully loads it says URL not found. Is this okay to happen?